# Properly respond to a HEAD request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

I have an `IHttpHandler` serving dynamically generated files. I wish to respond to `HEAD` requests to let the client know whether the file has changed.

I need to send the last change date and the file size, do I have to use `Response.AddHeader()` or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: So this is not a file that you're happy for IIS to serve?  Custom logic in other words?

Comment: I actually wish to generate the file on first request as it is time consuming, not at every internal change. The first HEAD or GET (re)generates the file if needed.

Comment: I don't think there's a cleaner way, or more accurately, I don't think setting the header like that is very dirty :)

Answer (score 0):

For the last modified time, you can call:

```
Response.Cache.SetLastModified()
```

Are you sure you need to set the size? The Framework usually takes care of that automatically, based on the actual size of the response.